# Javascript create IFrame

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create IFrame element within parent div. this is my javascript code:

```
var e = document.createElement('iframe');
e.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.com/);
e.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
e.style.border = "none";
e.style.overflow = "hidden";
e.style.overflowX = "hidden";
e.style.overflowY = "hidden";
var c = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
c.appendChild(e);
```

When I'm use this script in another site (emmbeded code), I'm getting this result:

```
<div>
<div id="parentDiv">
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" scrolling="no" style="width: 250px; height: 60px; border: medium none; overflow: hidden;">
</iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" scrolling="no" style="width: 250px; height: 60px; border: medium none; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/path" >
</div>
```

As you can see, the previous code is creating **two IFrames** (instead of one) and I'm don't know why.

Why this is happens?

Comment: Note, (probably not the problem at hand): `e.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.com/);` is missing it's closing quote. How is the javascript called? Is it in a function? Might you somehow be calling that function twice? We probably need to see a bit more relevant code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem, there is clearly something else going on here: http://jsfiddle.net/LEkyK/